# Can file.lastModified()>cal.getTimeInMillis() return true?

Tags: java, windows

Let's say I encounter this event on a Windows box.

> The time service has not synchronized the system time for 86400 seconds because none of the time service providers provided a usable time stamp. The time service will not update the local system time until it is able to synchronize with a time source. If the local system is configured to act as a time server for clients, it will stop advertising as a time source to clients. The time service will continue to retry and sync time with its time sources. Check system event log for other W32time events for more details. Run 'w32tm /resync' to force an instant time synchronization.

I'm thinking it could have bearing on currently running Java apps that use the GregorianCalendar class or Calendar.getInstance() method. To be specific, I have this code, where file.lastModified() is actually **a month earlier** than the date today. What are the chances that the "this should execute" part will not print?

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
File file = new File("/some/file/path");
if(file.lastModified()>cal.getTimeInMillis()){
    return;
}
System.out.println("This should execute, but will it certainly do so?");
```

Comment: Someone could have set the modified time into the future.

Comment: @EJP Could have. But I'm thinking if the system time could become 0 due to the said event.